# How to find out why my reputation has decreased?

Tags: support, reputation

I leave my computer running and so overnight TeXStackExchange kept running and I ended up with a reputation of 17,925. When I updated my view of the site to get the latest questions my reputation was decreased to 17,910. Why was this and how can I find out who caused the change? I would like to be able to ask for the reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer can be found on [the Reputation tab of your profile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12082/peter-wilson?tab=reputation), which contains all your historical reputation changes:

[image]

Another user unaccepted an answer of yours which was previously accepted. In that case, you lose the 15 reputation you gained when the answer was accepted, as indicated in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> - One of your *accepted* answers loses *accepted* status (i.e. unaccepted): **−15**